# how to protect my excel workbook project code without using xlsx

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, macros, xlsx

Dears,
i have an excel workbook hello.xlsm , this workbook cantains many macros.

if i save it as hello.xlsx then the macros will disappear from the project and the project will fail.

if i keep it as hello.xlsm , then you copy it to ubuntu machine, open it with libre office, you can view the project code even if it is password protected.

how to protect my password if i use xlsm ? 
or how to enable the macros if i use xlsx ?

Comment: Can you add the xlsm file to a password protected zip file or encrypt it with something like OpenSSL?

Comment: @Darren No i cannot, this xlsm file will be shared to end users.

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel isn't very good to protect your codes. You should look for other options, but you said you can't do that. A quick search in [google](https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=ZDurWOzNO8K0wATepYbIBQ#q=excel+break+password+protection) shows that it is fairly simple to break password protected sheets and codes. :/